# Use LInq 'Select Distinct' on a getter property

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have an Object, Company, which is a Property on another Object called Load

```
public Class Load
{
    private Company _Company;
    public Company Company
    {
        get
        {

            return _Company;

        }

        set
        {
            SetPropertyValue("Company", ref _Company, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get a distinct list of companies when i see the company drop down list. Currently I am seeing duplicates from the database. Can I accomplish this using Linq?

Comment: Yes, you can. Show us how you are binding the data to dropdownlist

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: I am using dev express XAF

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do by Linq. I am assuming you have companyID as a primary key.

List lstComp = new List();
var companyids = lstComp.Select(x => x.companyID).Distinct();

Comment: from question: `I need to get a distinct list of companies`, not *companyids*

Comment: I am trying this and I getting error: Cannot implicitly convert type List<string> to type Company. here is my code                `private Company _Company;  
 public Company Company
 {
   get
      {
          var distinctCompanies = _Company.Name.Cast<Company>()
                    .Where(x => x != null)
                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                    .Distinct()
                    .ToList();
      return distinctCompanies;

               
              
            }`

Comment: If companyid is not primary, then primary key need to be substitute instead of id. It looks like you have Company name that is duplicate, then place companyname instead of id